# how to disable http methods via iis

Tags: http, iis

We have unnecessary http methods enabled on one of our servers, and have been advised to disable any methods we do not require. The problem I have is that I am unsure of how to disable the unused methods. Can anyone provide an example or walkthrough on how to-do this ?

We are using a windows 2003 std server running IIS6

Comment: You would be better off with this on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

In IIS Manager, right click on the website and select Properties. Switch to the Home Directory tab, and click the Configuration button. In the list of application extensions, locate the extension that your web application uses and click the Edit button. In the Limit To field, specify the method you want to support and delete the ones you don't. This will work on a specific application. I don't exactly know how to apply this setting server wide unfortunately. This might lead you in the right direction though.

[image]